# Android: OpenGL ES 2.0 - Texture always black

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, texture-mapping

I'm trying to show a simple texture in OpenGL ES 2.0 (Android 4.0.4, Galaxy Nexus) as fullscreen background using a vertex and a fragment shader. The final result should be to display the camera image there, but for a start, simple texture from a file would be sufficient. I tested many things and for a short while it worked as I used OpenGL ES 1.x but as I plan to use shader for YUV->RGB conversion, I have to go with 2.0.

I have the following vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

void main() {
    gl_Position = position;
    textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy
}
```

and this fragment shader:

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;

uniform sampler2D videoFrame;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(videoFrame, textureCoordinate);
}
```

Shader creation as such should be ok, because when I write `gl_FragColor=vec4(1,0,0,0)` it works perfectly well and shows me a red background.

`OnSurfaceCreated` I do the following:

```
 a = makeFloatBuffer(squareVertices);
 b = makeFloatBuffer(textureVertices);
```

with `squareVertices` and `textureVertices` as follows:

```
static float squareVertices[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, };

static float textureVertices[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
        0.0f, 0.0f, };
```

`OnSurfaceChanged` I do the following:

```
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.raw.htc);
GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
```

R.raw.htc is 128x128 pixels png.

And `OnDrawFrame`:

```
    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    GLES20.glUniform1i(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "videoFrame"),0);

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    int x = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
    int y = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "inputTextureCoordinate");

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(x);        
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(x, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, a);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(y);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(y, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, b);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

The only thing I see is a completely black screen and I have no idea why. I saw some other posts here with similar problems but none of the proposed solution helped me out or no solution was given at all.

Comment: Did you test your texture coordinates? You can simply set them as fragment color (`gl_FragColor = vec4( textureCoordinate.x, textureCoordinate.y, 0.0, 1.0);`) to see if they are correct.

Comment: I think, they were correct. In the meantime, we could find a solution. I don't know the reason, why the version above did not work but I will post an answer later with the working Code then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said above, we could find a solution for the issue although we don't know exactly the reason why it is working now and was not before (we changed several things and suddenly it worked). Nonetheless I want to share our working version:

The shader are now completed to also do the YUV->RGB conversion:
The vertex shader:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec4 inputTextureCoordinate;

varying vec2 textureCoordinate;

 void main() {
      gl_Position = position;
      textureCoordinate = inputTextureCoordinate.xy;
 };
```

The fragment shader:

```
varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;
uniform sampler2D videoFrame;
uniform sampler2D videoFrame2;

void main(void) {
    highp float nx,ny,r,g,b,y,u,v;
    highp vec2 uv;
    highp vec4 txl,ux,vx;"
    nx=(textureCoordinate.x)/1024.0*720.0;
    ny=(textureCoordinate.y)/1024.0*480.0;
    y=texture2D(videoFrame,vec2(nx,ny)).r;
    uv=texture2D(videoFrame2,vec2(nx,ny)).ag;
    y=1.1643*(y-0.0625);
    u=uv[0]-0.5;
    v=uv[1]-0.5;
    r=y+1.5958*v;
    g=y-0.39173*u-0.81290*v;
    b=y+2.017*u;

    gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,1);
};
```

`OnSurfaceCreated` is still the same but the definition of the vertices changed a bit:

```
static float squareVertices[] = { -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, };

private float textureVertices[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
        1.0f, 0.0f, };
```

`OnSurfaceChanged`:

```
    buffer = new int[2];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(2, buffer, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        int texture = buffer[i];
        Log.v("Texture", "Texture is at " + texture);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        GLES20.glPixelStorei(GLES20.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, GLES20.GL_TRUE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    }

    buf = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++) {
        buf[i] = 0;
    }
    buf2 = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; i++) {
        buf2[i] = -128;
    }

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffer[0]);

    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE, 1024,
            1024, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            ByteBuffer.wrap(buf));

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffer[1]);

    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA,
            512, 512, 0, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            ByteBuffer.wrap(buf2));
```

`OnDrawFrame`:

```
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffer[0]);

    GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, Util.CAMWIDTH,
            Util.CAMHEIGHT, GL10.GL_LUMINANCE, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            ByteBuffer.wrap(mBuffer, 0, Util.CAMWIDTH * Util.CAMHEIGHT));

    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, buffer[1]);

    GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(
            GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            Util.CAMWIDTH / 2,
            Util.CAMHEIGHT / 2,
            GL10.GL_LUMINANCE_ALPHA,
            GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            ByteBuffer.wrap(mBuffer, Util.CAMWIDTH * Util.CAMHEIGHT,
                    Util.CAMWIDTH / 2 * Util.CAMHEIGHT).slice());

    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, .0f, .0f, .0f);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(program);

    GLES20.glUniform1i(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "videoFrame"),
            0);
    GLES20.glUniform1i(GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(program, "videoFrame2"),
            1);

    GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    int x = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "position");
    int y = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(program, "inputTextureCoordinate");

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(x);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(x, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, a);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(y);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(y, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, b);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Comment: `decodeResource` should receive a `BitmapFactory Options` object with `isScaled` set to `false` so that it stays a power of 2. For anyone checking this snippet and thinking "Hey, my code is correct".

Comment: Optimal naming convention, by the way! `a`, `b`, `x`, `y`. `buf` looks huge among the others.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring your texture coordinate as 4 components, instead of what looks like it should be 2. Code looks fine otherwise.

Comment: I assume you mean changing ``GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(y, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, b);`` to ``GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(y, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, b);`` ?
Unfortunately, it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
```

These 2 lines of code did the trick for me

```
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

I also needed these 2 in order to display a PNG file